# Boost cannot assign requested address

Tags: c++, linux, boost, message-queue, interprocess

I have  peace of code that worked for months, which is built on c++ boost inter process library. Two days ago I've started getting this exception without  any code change:
'bind: Cannot assign requested address'
this exception is due to this source:

> '''
>           _messageQueue = std::make_unique(
>                   bip::open_or_create,
>                   messageQueueName,
>                   maxNumMsg,
>                   maxMsgSize);

Can it be caused due to the machine?

edit:
It seems that when running first time with sudo, second time works.
can it be a permission issue and where can I find the socket after creation (usually I find Linux socket in tmp folder)?

edit2:
The queue is not open because whenever I change the queue name the issue repeats itself.

Comment: `strace` (on Linux at least) could be helpful. For some reason (alternatives depend on socket type) binding the socket fails. Perhaps you have an instance of measage queue server already running? Or some other server app, which uses the same port or file.

Comment: There's way too little info to make guesses even, especially considering that the code used to work. Please, start with the [tour] and read [ask]. If you have problems with code, extract a [mcve] and post that alongside. Also, just throw that error message at a websearch and read a bit what it means.